# Using a Formula multiple times in one cell with only one value changing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a pretty long formula which I want to use multiple times in a cell. I want to reference to the sheets 'Project 2' to "Project 20'. Since this formula is rather long i would like to know if there is a way to reference to that formula and just tell Excel to increase the number of the project by 1 so i dont have to use the whole formula 20 times in one cell. The details of this formula are not important. I would just like to know if there is some kind function i could use to have it like this:

'Original Formula (Project1)+Original Formula (Project 2)...Original Formula (Project 20)

**Original formula:**

```
    If(And('Project 2'!$K$2<=Today();Today()<='Project 2'!$U$2;COUNTIF('Project 2'!$A$6:$A$100;Sheet1!A6)=1);", ";"");
   IF(AND('Project 2'!$K$2<=TODAY();TODAY()<='Project 2'!$U$2;COUNTIF('Project 2'!$A$6:$A$100;Sheet1!A6)=1);"P2";"")
```

I googled, looked through stackoverflow and tried to use chatgpt but I couldn't define my problem enough to get the right search results. I tried to work with the name manager but I couldn't manage to get excel to iterate the number up to Project 20

Comment: try with indirect() and reference a range of cells with 2 to 20.

Comment: Just for clarity: If you were to manually write out this monster formula, it would be your current formula's length times 20 (Like 4500 characters long)? You are looking for a better way to get the same results. Is that accurate?

Comment: You can refer to all sheets like this: `=SUM('Project 1:Project 20'!A1)` --> search for  3D reference

Comment: What's important to know is what your goal is of the formula. Do you want to look at the Projects one at a time and have separate results, or all at once?

A little data to reproduce would also be nice. ( https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables )

Answer (score 1):

Working from my assumption in the comments, you could probably get crafty with the `MAP()` and `INDIRECT()` functions to pull this off.

For a simple example, imagine we are working in Sheet2 column A and we have a list of numbers in the first 20 rows

[image]

For our simple function, we just want to add together any numbers that are less than 100. *Clearly we can use `sumif()` for that, but that likely won't work for your complex example.*

---

**Using Indirect to refer to a location in excel**

First, we use indirect to reference a cell:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & 1)
```

That will spit out `123`. You can use this same logic in your formula like `=INDIRECT("'Project " & 2 & "'!$K$2")` to get the cell `K2` value from sheet `Project 2`.

Now constructing our more simple formula:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & 1)<100, INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & 1), 0)
```

Again, that's a silly way of doing things, but it will make sense in a minute. This function will return the value in A1 if it is less than 100.

---

**Iterating over the function for each project page**

Next we want to build 20 of these functions, dynamically, and for the results of each function, shove it into an array. We don't want that array as output, but it will help solve the bigger problem. To do this we are going to use `MAP()`, `SEQUENCE()` and `LAMBDA()`.

1. `SEQUENCE()` will be used to generate an array that has a sequence of numbers from 1 to 20 for each of your sheets
2. `MAP()` will take that sequence as its first parameter and then call the `LAMBDA()` function
3. Each time `MAP()` calls the `LAMBDA()` function the output will be stuck in an array. We will end up with an array of 20 values corresponding to the output of the `=IF()` formula we wrote.

```
=MAP(SEQUENCE(1,20), LAMBDA(x, IF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & x)<100, INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & x), 0)))
```

In short, we create an array containing values 1 through 20 with `SEQUENCE()`. We pass each value into the `LAMBDA()` where we refer to that value as variable `x`. We then use that variable `x` in our `IF(INDIRECT())` function we built earlier.

---

**Summing the results**

Finally we toss `SUM()` across this to sum up each of the values returned (a 0 if it was more than 100, and the value from the cell if it was less than 100)

```
 =SUM(MAP(SEQUENCE(1,20), LAMBDA(x, IF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & x)<100, INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & x), 0))))
```

Output: `166`

---

**Your solution:**

Using this same logic for your big nasty formula, you would end up with the following:

```
=SUM(MAP(SEQUENCE(1;20); LAMBDA(x; If(And(INDIRECT("'Project " & x & "'!$K$2")<=Today();Today()<=INDIRECT("'Project " & x & "'!$U$2");COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Project " & x & "'!$A$6:$A$100");Sheet1!A6)=1);", ";"");IF(AND(INDIRECT("'Project " & x & "'!$K$2")<=TODAY();TODAY()<=INDIRECT("'Project " & x & "'!$U$2");COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Project " & x & "'!$A$6:$A$100");Sheet1!A6)=1);"P2";""))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it out next week when i am back in the office but from what i understand this is exactly what i would need.